# How to round to 2 decimal places in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I am using jquery datatable aocolumns to round the specific columns to two decimal places but it seems like i am unable to get the correct regular expression for this or may be their is something wrong with my logic.

```
"aoColumnDefs": [ {
                        "aTargets": [ 7 ],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            var formmatedvalue = data.replace(/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/, "")
                             return formmatedvalue;
                        }
                    }],
```

The output for that column should be

```
120.02
1560.56
565645.25
124995.89
etc .....
```

Any possible solution for this?

Comment: in your js before sending it to database set it to 2 decimal by `toFixed(2)`

Comment: I am not sending data, it is using ajax request to pull data from server i do not think their is any possible way to format the data returned.

Comment: everything is possible..when sending the data from ajax you can set it for example when getting the value from the input text and sending it ajax send the value with `.toFixed(2)` then the value you will save in database will be fixed to 2 decimal

Comment: I am pulling data from database to display rather than saving it so i have to format the data on some column render function of datatable

Comment: share your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use this function:

```
function (data, type, full) {
     return data.toString().match(/\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/g)[0];
}
```

You would be looking for matching the part you need and not to replace.

Comment: This method doesn't round and also doesn't guarantee that the result will have two decimal places.

Answer (score 13):

**For decimal places upto 2 you can use the following code in datatable**

```
 function (data, type, full) {
         return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);
    }
```